# Bring down the image by overflowing the div CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to bring down the image which i will show you in someway below

the basic structure is

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1">
      </div><!-- end grid 1 -->


      <div class="col-lg-9">
           <div class="col-sm-6" style="min-height:100%;"><img class="img-responsive" src="url" />
            </div>
           <div class="col-sm-6">
           </div>
      </div><!-- end grid 9 -->


      <div class="col-lg-2">
      </div><!-- end grid 2 -->
    </div><!-- end row -->
```

The image is displayed inside the bootstrap class col-sm-6..  Now, i need to bring it down by some pixels.
here i add http://jsfiddle.net/vcptv09b/ jsfiddle...just bring down google image little bit down without increasing the background size...
i tried absolute position and margin top..its collapses all..

Comment: have you tried `padding-top` ?

Comment: please provide Demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)/[Codepen](http://codepen.io/) or provide link of website

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="min-height:100%; margin-bottom: -20px;"><img class="img-responsive" src="url" />
```

Like this?